# Guava Join 3rd parameter NULL

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guava

Who can explain what this ?

```
 public final String join(@Nullable Object first, @Nullable Object second,Object... rest) {
        return this.join((Iterable)iterable(first, second, rest));
    }

private static Iterable<Object> iterable(final Object first, final Object second, final Object[] rest) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(rest);
        return new AbstractList() {
            public int size() {
                return rest.length + 2;
            }

            public Object get(int index) {
                switch(index) {
                case 0:
                    return first;
                case 1:
                    return second;
                default:
                    return rest[index - 2];
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Why is method join not like this - join(Object...args) ???
Actually if I have some example :

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";

public String getFullName(){
   return Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join(first, lastName, null);
}
```

NullPointerException is occured !!! It looks weird.
But if I invoke :

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
String parentName = null;

  public String getFullName(){
       return Joiner.on(" ").skipNulls().join(first, lastName, parentName);
    }
```

**OUTPUT** : John Doe.

Answer (score 3):

In the method

```
join(@Nullable Object first, @Nullable Object second, Object... rest)
```

the last parameter `rest` is an `Object` array, that's `Object[]`.

In the first case:

```
join(first, lastName, null)
```

when you use `null` there is no way to know what type it is, so it's assumed to be `(Object[])` (as it matches the method signature) so the parameter `rest` is `null`.

The second example `parentName` is a `String` so:

```
join(first, lastName, parentName)
```

is equivalent to:

```
join(first, lastName, (String) null)
```

where `rest` is not of type `Object[]`. As it doesn't directly match `Object...` (`Object[]`) it's converted into an array of one position where `rest[0]` is `null` (`rest = [null]`)

Check out this example: http://ideone.com/PPwU05

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    varargs(null);
    varargs((String) null);
    varargs(new String[]{"Hi!"});
    varargs();
}

public static void varargs (Object... array) {
    if (array == null) {
        System.out.println("Is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Is null
[null]
[Hi!]
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the signature not `join(Object... args)`

Simply because the Guava team wants you to make sure that you actually *join* objects. To do that, you need at least 2 arguments. So the first two arguments are not checked at runtime with an exception, but at compile-time by explicitly forcing you to use more than one object.

So it's a design to force you to write correctly. A side effect is that indeed, you can't add `null` as third parameter without getting an exception. If you want to explicitly use the varargs and use `null`, just write the following:

```
Joiner joiner = ...
joiner.join(Arrays.asList(firstName, lastName, null));
```